# How to add key to child in a list using react?

Tags: reactjs

i am looping through the matched patterns using string.matchAll method. in doing so i get the error each child in list should have unique key prop.

what i am trying to do?

i am trying to match a pattern from the input string say "i am [2@some user]"
then frame a string like below,
    "i am `<strong>some user</strong>`"

What i have tried?

Used the snippet below to match and frame the output string. it works all fine. but it just throws a warning "each child in list should have unique key prop" and that happens in line where strong tag is. how can i fix it. new to using react

```
match_pattern = (string_to_parse) => {
    const pattern = /\[\d+@(?<name>[^\]\r\n]*)]/g;
    const matches = string_to_parse.matchAll(pattern);
    let prev_match_pos = 0;
    const string_parts = [];
    for (const match of matches) {
        string_parts.push(string.substring(prev_match_pos, match.index));
        string_parts.push(<strong>{match.groups.name}</strong>);
        prev_match_pos = match.index + match[0].length;
    }
    string_parts.push(string_to_parse.substring(prev_match_pos, 
    string.length));
    return string_parts;
};
```

the strong in the for loop needs a key prop and what could be that key prop. could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Comment: _“what i am trying to do?”_ - good question - and one that you should answer first of all, because just throwing a piece of code at us tells us rather little. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: somehow missed some parts of question will edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used a `for (variable in variables)` to do some functionality. This structure is used to do a loop on an object. Usually when want to have a loop on an array(which is more common) we use the array item index as a key value for example:

```
    for (let i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        return(
            <div key={i}>

            </div>
        );
    }
```

or when we use `.map` function for array loops:

```
    array.map((item,index)=>
        return(
            <div key={index+1}>

            </div>
        )
    )
```

But in the case of objects if any object in your loop have an unique id it could be used as key value. and if it did not contains any id you can add to it before you begin your loop. So your code will be like this:

```
for (const match of matches) {
    string_parts.push(string.substring(prev_match_pos, match.index));
    string_parts.push(<strong key={match.group.id}>{match.groups.name}</strong>);
    prev_match_pos = match.index + match[0].length;
}
```

I hope it is helpful. If it was please vote me up:)

Comment: thanks. changed this  <strong key={match.group.id}>  to this <strong key={match.index}> and it works. since there is no id in group property for match.